# Second submit button not showing

Tags: php, form-submit, submit-button

I have created a form whose method is "POST" and action is "#", indicating to send the data to the same page.
Now after submitting the form,
A second form appears below which fetches data(according to the selection on first form) from database and gives the user a control to edit the record.

EVERYTHING IS WORKING GOOD AND WELL
The only problem is "*Second form submit button doesn't show up"

My Code of that particular page:(editcategory.php)

```
<?php
    require_once("admin_panel.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Users</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/footer.css">
    <style>
        .bodystart{
            margin-top:2%;
            margin-left:25%;
        }
        h1{
            font-size:xx-large;
        }
        table {
            border-collapse: separate;
            border-spacing:5px 5px;
            width: auto;
            color: #588c7e;
            font-family:"Lucida Console", "Courier New", monospace;
            font-size: 20px;
            text-align: left;
        }
        th {
            background-color: #588c7e;
            color: white;
        }
        option:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #f2f2f2
        }
        .submitnewcat{
            margin-top:3%;
            color:#ffffff;
            padding:5px;
            border-radius:10 px;
            background-color:#4CAF50;
            cursor:pointer;
        }
        form{
            margin-top:5%;
        }
        input,select{
            border-style:inset;
            border-left:6px solid green;
            background-color:#ced6e0;
            padding: 12px 15px;
            border-radius:5px;
        }
        .catidcont{
            background-color:#c7ecee;
            cursor:default;
        }
        label{
            padding:12px 15px;
            font-size:larger;
            background-color:#130f40;
            color:#ffffff;
            border-radius:5px;
            border:2px solid red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="bodystart">        
        <h1><i>Edit Category</i></h1>

        <form method="POST" action="#">
            <label>Select Category</label>
            <?php
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM category";
                $result = mysqli_query($db_conn,$sql);
                echo "<select name='catset' required>";
                echo "<option value=''>Select</option>";
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
                }
                echo "</select>";
            ?>
            <button class="submitnewcat" name="submit3" type="submit" value="Submit">Fetch Details</button>
        </form>
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST["submit3"])==true){
                function validate($data){
                $data = trim($data);
                $data = stripslashes($data);
                $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
                return $data;
                }
                $x=(int)$_POST['catset'];
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM category a WHERE a.id=$x";
                $result = $db_conn->query($sql);
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
                    echo "<form method='POST' action='updatecategory.php'";
                        echo "<input type='hidden' readonly>";
                        echo "<label>Category ID</label>";
                        echo "<input type='number' name='catid' value=$x readonly style='cursor:no-drop;'><br><br><br>";
                        echo "<label>New Category Name</label>";
                        echo "<input type='text' name='newcatname' required placeholder='".$row['name']."'>";
                        echo "<label>Status</label>";
                        echo "<select name='newstat' required>";
                        if($row["status"]==1){
                            $catstat="Active";
                            
                            echo "<option value='".$row['status']."' selected>$catstat</option>";
                            echo "<option value='2'>Disabled</option>";
                        }
                        else{
                            $catstat="Disabled";
                            echo "<option value='1'>Active</option>";
                            echo "<option value='".$row['status']."' selected>$catstat</option>";
                        }
                        echo "<button class='submigtnewcat' name='submit4' type='submit' value='Submit'>Fetch Details</button>";
                    echo "</form>";
                }
                        
            } ?>
    </div>
</body>
<?php
require_once("include/footer.php");?>
</html>
```

Snippet of my page [image]

Comment: You dont close the `<select>` dropdown before outputting the second button

Comment: _Note_ Cannot think what this is used for? `echo "<input type='hidden' readonly>";`

Comment: _Note_ If you put your footer after the `</body>` you wont see it

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should alway use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: ` echo "<input type='hidden' readonly>"; `
I used this as a psedo because the next line ` echo "<label>Category ID</label>"; ` wasn't getting styled. @RiggsFolly

Comment: Suggest you close the `<form>` tag properly then it will get styled as it will not be confused by an unclosed form tag `echo "<form method='POST' action='updatecategory.php'>";`

Comment: Thank you @RiggsFolly for clearing out my typo
And also, I will switch to `mysqli_`

Comment: You also dont seem to use the `validate()` function, so you could remove that code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is bug you have not close the tag of select so button is not displaying .

i hope you have got your answer .

```
                  echo "<select name='newstat' required>";
                    if($row["status"]==1){
                        $catstat="Active";
                        
                        echo "<option value='".$row['status']."' selected>$catstat</option>";
                        echo "<option value='2'>Disabled</option>";
                    }
                    else{
                        $catstat="Disabled";
                        echo "<option value='1'>Active</option>";
                        echo "<option value='".$row['status']."' selected>$catstat</option>";
                    }
                   echo "</select>";
```

Comment: We do not normally provide an answer to a TYPO. We make a comment to put the OP on the right track and then close and delete the question. TYPO's are almost never any use to others, and that is one of the prime purposes of SO.

Comment: @ RiggsFolly   thanks in future i will give answer in comment if there is typo error .

Comment: Thank you @RakeshkumarOad
works just fine now